# How to solve for the operator such that $\hat{O} e^{-a x} = a^{-1/2} e^{-a x} $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, differential-operators

I would like to solve for an differential-integro operator $\hat{O}$ (involving the variable $x$ only) which acts on an exponential function $\exp(-a x)$ to bring out a factor of $a^{-1/2}$:
$$ \hat{O} e^{- a x} = a^{-1/2} e^{-a x}.$$
I am not sure how to approach such a problem. Obviously if I needed
$$ \hat{O} e^{- a x} = a e^{-a x},$$
the answer would be $\hat{O} = -d/dx$, and if I needed
$$ \hat{O} e^{- a x} = \frac{1}{a} e^{-a x}, $$
the answer would be $ \hat{O} = - \int dx. $

What approach can I use to get $\hat{O}$ for the problem in the title? I am guessing some convolution would do it. If my original problem doesn't have a clear solution, is there a name for this type of functional calculus which solves for unknown operators on continuous functions?

Comment: It's clear you need a 1/2 fractional antiderivative. Look up fractional calculus and choose the convention that fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks! I'm actually 10 mins into digging into that right now : ) 
The point stands though that I need to figure out what the "category" of this kind of problem is - I have never run into the need for this before. Basically I have some really tough Bessel function integrals and need to convert one into another using a trick.

Comment: Unfortunately $D^{1/2} e^{-a x} = -\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi x}} + \sqrt{\frac{4a}{\pi}}F(\sqrt{a x})$, where $F$ is Dawson's integral, so the fractional derivative alone doesn't quite do it.

Comment: Like I said, choose the convention that fits. It seems like you chose the Fourier convention and lost. Try another one. Unlike other areas of analysis, the different fractional derivative conventions are *not* equivalent.

Comment: That was Caputo. Riemann-Liouville similarly gives a Dawson integral times $\sqrt{a}$ which does not solve the problem. Which convention do you suggest?

Comment: I gather Leibniz's approach would work if it were defined as an integro-differential operator.

Comment: Some experimentation gives that $\hat{O} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(-1/2)}\int_{-\infty}^x \frac{1}{(x-t)^{3/2}}$ works. Maybe this is the Liouville definition.